# IIS long polling AsyncController

Tags: multithreading, iis, request, signals, long-polling

I ran into an interesting problem in IIS and I would like to get to the bottom of it.

I have an app that long polls . i have implemented my own long polling.

A request comes in. I block that req and write to it from my worker thread. 
then everything finish. I signal. And the thread that was handling the GET request is releases.

I am not talking about scalability here. It is not my concern. 
Just for testing, I ONLY make concurrent get requests. 
So there is only 2 threads running. ONE for the get request and one worker thread. 
I know that Request threads exits safely.I put a print right before the Action of the Controller returns. (Is that good enough?)

what I run into is. IIS slows down after a while even though I am exiting the GET thread.

So why is it slowing down ? When I implemented with AsyncController it does not slow down.
I know AsyncControllers attach and detach the threads from the pool. But if I have 25 thread available in my pool and If I have one active thread for worker and one thread that enters and exits for the get. I am sort of lost. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that you are "exiting the GET thread"? I think you should post your actual code.

Comment: Each request is handled as a separate thread. The get thread is the thread that initially handling the GET Request(same thread I block and later release).